# To prove $(A-B) \cup (B-C) \cup (C-A) = A \cup B \cup C - A \cap B \cap C$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

To prove $(A-B) \cup (B-C) \cup (C-A) = A \cup B \cup C - A \cap B \cap C$

It can be done by set operation method. But the process is very lengthy. So I am trying it by showing that each is a subset of the other and hence are equal.

But I am finding difficulty in the part $A \cup B \cup C - A \cap B \cap C \subset (A-B) \cup (B-C) \cup (C-A) $.

Comment: Both sides are "the elements that are in *one* of $A$, $B$, $C$, but not in the *all* of them.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try. Let $x \in A \cup B \cup C - A\cap B\cap C$.

If $x\in A$ and ($x \not\in B$), then $x \in A-B$.

If $x \in A$ and $x\in B$, then $x\not \in C$, then $x\in B-C$.

Thus, $x \in RHS$.

It is the same with the cases $x\in B$ or $x\in C$.